# Access build.xml properties from Java

Tags: java, android, ant, properties

I have an Android application that is by default built with Ant.

There is `build.xml` file which loads `local.proerties` file. I would like to add my custom property (for example Google Maps apiKey) and access it in Java classes - for example in some MainActivity.

How can I achieve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your ant script modify the Java source file containing the API key or a properties file bundled with the application, using the [replace](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replace.html) task or the [copy](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html) task with a filterset.

Answer (score 0):

Ant provides a target called "sysproperty". Its like a property tag, but it sets the java System.property. So, you can do something like:

<sysproperty name="foo" value="$THE_EXTRA_PROPERTY">

where "THE_EXTRA_PROPERTY" is the extra property that you added to the properties file that gets loaded.